# Fancybox animation jumps to top corner of page

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, wordpress, fancybox

I am working on a site for a client, and have included the fancybox script for images. The issue I'm having is related to the animation itself. It appears to jump to the top left corner of the window before animating in. After that it works correctly. I can't seem to figure out why it is doing that glitchy animation though.

Any ideas?

[Link to site...](http://clients.paradigmcreative.com/hfsfoods/packaging/)

Comment: Download the latest master,it's fixed there https://github.com/fancyapps/fancyBox/archive/master.zip

Comment: I have the latest version installed. The issue remains. It's not the page behind that is the issue, but the animation itself.

Comment: You have a `$('.fancybox-wrap').swipe()` in your `afterShow` callback that might be why

Comment: Unfortunately that's not it either. That is actually to create the touch functionality for mobile. Removing it doesn't affect the animation jump. :/ I'm wracking my brain here.

Answer (score -1):

Check out this article http://davekiss.com/prevent-fancybox-from-jumping-to-the-top-of-the-page/ on solving the same problem. The author suggests this:

```
$('.image').fancybox({
    padding: 0,
    helpers: {
        overlay: {
          locked: false
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: This doesn't solve the issue, it's just a workaround. Many people may not like to be able to scroll the content behind fancybox (this what will happen if `locked` is set to `false`.) This is a **temporary workaround** to an issue that may create another for some scenarios. This was a bug and **it has been corrected** in the latest master https://github.com/fancyapps/fancyBox/archive/master.zip

Comment: Besides the fact that it's not the issue I'm having anyway. My issue is not with the page behind the fancybox...but with the animation of the fancybox itself. The actual box jumps to the top during the animation...not the page.